# PHP Вызвать элемент из ассоциативного массива по индексу

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив типа `['34234' => [...], '452245' => [...], ...]`, Мне нужно по очереди и по кругу вызывать эти элементы

- не в одном цыкле, а передавая в функцию и индекс текущего элемента и массив - должен получить следующий элемент (или первый, если предыдущий был последним)

Вопрос - как надежно и оптимально получить индекс пары ключ-значение, имея ключ, и как потом вызвать ту же пару по этому ключу? Порядок важен.

```
$array = ['44124' => 'mom', '34525' => 'dad', '535345' => 'sis', '342352' => 'bro'];
$current = 1;
$element = $array[*магия*$current]; //ожидаю получить 'dad'
```

Дисклеймер: я уже понял всю неоптимальность своего алгоритма, и что можно (нужно) сделать по другому. Но вот есть такая задача, и интересно какими способами можно решить.

Comment: $keys = array_keys($array); $element = $array[$keys[$current]] ?? $array[$keys[0]];

Comment: ну или $element = $array[$keys[$current+1]] ?? $array[$keys[0]]; я не очень понял, какой там следующий, а какой последующий

Comment: @Ипатьев все верно) Отлично и лаконично получилось

Comment: @Ипатьев Хорошее решение. Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 нет, я стараюсь не тратить ответы на такие мелочи. Потом сложно искать нормальные полезные посты по важным вопросам, которые могут пригодиться в следующий раз.